# How to read innodb row which is created by after insert trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers, locking

Let me come to the point directly. I have two tables named A and B. In table A I have a trigger(AFTER INSERT) which is responsible to insert a row in table B with NEW.ID in it. In table B there is also a trigger(AFTER INSERT) which calls php external script using the mysql UDF and in the UDF I pass the NEW.table_A_ID. Now the script tries to access the newly inserted row in table A.

The problem: I am unable to read the newly inserted row in table A. I can read the n-1th row but not the nth row. By default the mysql autocommit is 1 and engine Im using is INNODB. What is the workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of an InnoDB transaction, the row inserted into table A is not yet committed when the AFTER INSERT trigger is fired. The INSERT statement is not "complete" until after the trigger finishes.

The transaction isolation level of a second database session will determine whether that session can see uncommitted data or not. Default transaction isolation level is **`REPEATABLE READ`**.

InnoDB also provides a (more strict) **`SERIALIZABLE`** isolation level, an (Oracle-like) **`READ COMMITTED`** isolation level, and a **`READ UNCOMMITTED`** isolation level.

Note that AUTOCOMMIT doesn't really matter in the scenario you describe; the "commit" action will only occur AFTER the INSERT statement returns, and that won't happen until the AFTER INSERT trigger completes.

---

If you inserted rows into a **MyISAM** table in the trigger, then those rows would be visible to another database session. (This is one way to achieve an Oracle-like AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION in MySQL.)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. You mean I change my db engine from innodb to myisam. Isn't there any other workaround?

Comment: @SURFER: What I was saying was, if I had to do this in Oracle, one approach would be to add an "extra" table, and do an insert into it, using an AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION, so I could do the insert into the "extra" table and COMMIT just that, and then continue with processing...  that row inserted into the "extra" table would be available to other sessions, even if I hadn't yet done a commit of the original transaction.  I was saying that using an "extra" table using the MyISAM engine emulates the Oracle AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION behavior.

Comment: The table B in this case is extra table. How can I change it from innodb to myisam?

Comment: @SURFER: the syntax to do that would simply be `"ALTER TABLE B ENGINE=MyISAM"` ... but that will throw an error if there are any foreign key constraints defined for the table, or referencing the table.  Even with table B converted to MyISAM, that won't "fix" the problem querying table A.

Comment: Solved my problem using SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED